# finding similar neighbourhoods in cell arrays matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of cells,

example in the image below

[image: cell array of intergers]

I have been trying to use regionprops or any other tool to calculate the amount of neighbours with identical first index

for example below there are 5 cells circled in blue which are neighbours and have 1st index = 1 therefore there neighbourhood should = 5 for all of them and similar with the black cells

[image]

does anyone know of anyway to calculate this?

thank you.

Comment: so you can only go up down left right, not diagonally? and also, are all those 0s always 0s? i.e you only have 3 integers in each cell?

Comment: that's right only von-Neumann neighbours, In fact if the only way to do this was to do diagonals too then that would still be usefull

Comment: You missed two, the upper left two also have `2` as first index and are directly connected to the blue ones

Comment: the zeros in the other cells do not remain zero

Comment: I didn't include the upper left two because theyre not direct neighbours they are joined by a diagonal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to extract *just* the first index from each array, create a matrix (similar to a labels matrix) and then use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#inputarg_L) on that.

```
%// Extracts the first value of each cell
firstValue = cellfun(@(x)x(1), cellArray);

%// Computes region properties using this matrix as a label matrix
result = regionprops(firstValue, property_to_compute);
```

The result can then be applied back to the full cell array as necessary.

Alternately, you could loop through the various first index values and compute the connected components using [`bwconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html).

```
uniqueVals = unique(firstValue);
for k = 1:numel(uniqueVals)
    CC(k) = bwconncomp(firstValue == uniqueVals(k));
end
```